# AndroidLauncher cannot find assets, but DesktopLauncher can

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to make an android app, I am using Android Studio and LibGDX. The problem is that my app keeps crashing since it cannot find my sprite.

When I do :`player = new Texture(Gdx.files.local("/data/Sprites/sqr_blue.png"));`
my `DesktopLauncher` can find the file so it works correctly, but my `AndroidLauncher` cannot find the file, resulting in the app crashing.

Previously I did `player = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("/data/Sprites/sqr_blue.png"));` , but it did not work with the `DesktopLauncher` nor the `AndroidLauncher`.

If I do `Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath()` it will return *O:\Stuff\GameName\android\assets* which is also the path I set under the working directory of the `DesktopLauncher`.

The absolute path of my file is `O:\Stuff\GameName\android\assets\data\Sprites\sqr_blue.png`

I also tried a Gradle Sync, but it did nothing to help the situation.

I am quite confused on what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `player = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Sprites/sqr_blue.png"));`

Notice that there is no slash at the beginning. This little slash was breaking your path.